# Mypy annotation for any type but None

Tags: python, mypy

How can I annotate a type that can be anything but `None`? In other words, this type is `Any` but is not `None`.

Comment: You can't. There's no way to express that.

Comment: Interesting question, do you have a specific use case in mind where "give me anything you want, as long as it is not exactly `None`" is a useful requirement?

Comment: @NiklasMertsch Imagine a function that takes in a file path, and determines the nature of the file, and returns a proper objects that represent the content of the file (e.g., `str` if it determines the file is plain text and `PIL.Image` if it determines the files is an image, and `bytes` if it's anything else). Further imagine that the function is in a package that allows user to register their own type determiner and handler. And the design decides that the return type can't be None. Then the return type can be virtually anything but None.

Comment: I see, but why would you want type annotations on such a thing? And what's the actual real-life benefit of a `AllExcept[None]` over `Any`? Should a user not be allowed to register a handler that can result in `None`? In my opinion this would be the perfect example of a good place for `Any`.

Comment: @NiklasMertsch That's the point: A user must not register a handler that can result in `None`. How much the benefit of an `AllExcept[None]` offers is somewhat subjective, I think. One may argue it really doesn't bring anything, but one can also argue it clarifies what the function might do a bit better.

Answer (score -2):

You can do `Union[int, str, ...]` but exclude `None` from that union.

Comment: This won't be `Any` though

Comment: @xuhdev if the return type cannot be `None`, then the return type would not be `Any`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `Any` - `None`

Comment: If you don't want to use `Union`, you can just create your own type.

Comment: Any suggestions how?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type Also feel free to create a feature enhancement request for this in https://bugs.python.org/ if you feel that this kind of data type is common.

Comment: @Flair -- typing.Type isn't something that lets you create a type. Rather, it's a way to express the type of a type. For example, if we do `var1 = 3`, the type of `var1` is "int". But what if we do `var2 = int` -- what's the type of `var2`? In this case, it would be "typing.Type[int]".

Comment: I was suggesting to create your own type, and as shown in the docs, you would annotate with your own type. I was not suggesting that `typing.Type` would create your type for you; that would be outside of the scope of type notation.